# Error al insertar datos desde php a mysql por los caracteres especiales

Tags: php, mysql, caracteres

No puedo insertar ciertos textos desde php a mysql, cuando tiene ciertos carácteres especiales simplemente falla y no insertar nada... he probado cambiar configuraciones desde la BD (las tablas y collation de la BD) pero nada... intentado convertir los datos antes de insertar pero tampoco... voy a adjuntar el código y tal vez me puedan orientar.

```
    <?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","xxxx","xxxx","xxxx");

$acentos = $conn->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
mysqli_set_charset($conn, 'utf8' );
/*
mysqli_character_set_name($conn);

if (!mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8")) {
    printf("", mysqli_error($conn));
    exit();
} else {
    printf("", mysqli_character_set_name($conn));
}
*/

?>
```

y este es el código del backend.

```
<?php
    require_once ("../../conn.php");

    if (!empty($_POST['name']))
    {

        $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,(strip_tags($_POST["name"],ENT_QUOTES)));
        $category = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,(strip_tags($_POST["category"],ENT_QUOTES)));
        $price = floatval($_POST["price"]);
        $supplier = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,(strip_tags($_POST["supplier"],ENT_QUOTES)));  
        $description = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,(strip_tags($_POST["description"],ENT_QUOTES)));
        $tech = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,(strip_tags($_POST["tech"],ENT_QUOTES)));
        $video = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,(strip_tags($_POST["video"],ENT_QUOTES)));
        $stock = intval($_POST["stock"]);
        $fileInfo = PATHINFO($_FILES["images"]["name"]);
        $filePdf = $_FILES["pdf"]["name"];
        define('folderDirectory',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/pcinnovations-master/POS/");

        if (empty($_FILES["images"]["name"]))
        {
            $locationImg="";
        }
        else
        {
            if ($fileInfo['extension'] == "jpg" OR $fileInfo['extension'] == "png") {
                $newFilename = $fileInfo['filename'] . "." . $fileInfo['extension'];
                if(!file_exists(folderDirectory."upload")){
                    mkdir(folderDirectory."upload" , 0777,true);
                }
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["images"]["tmp_name"], folderDirectory."upload/" . $newFilename);
                $locationImg = "upload/" . $newFilename;
            }
            else
            {
                echo json_encode(['error'=>true,'msg'=>'Photo not added. Please upload JPG or PNG photo only!']);
                $locationImg = "";
            }
        }

        $locationPdf = "";

        $sql = "call addproduct('$category','$name','$price','$stock','$locationImg','$supplier','$description','$video','$tech','$locationPdf')";
        //mysqli_set_charset($conn,$sql);
        $query = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        echo mysqli_error($conn);
        if ($query)
        {

            if(empty($_FILES["pdf"]["name"]))
            {
                $locationPdf = "";
            }
            else
            {
                if(PATHINFO($filePdf)['extension'] !='pdf') // verificamos que sea pdf
                {   
                    $errors[] = 'File not added. You must upload only file pdf';
                    echo json_encode(['error'=>true,'msg'=>'File not added. You must upload only file pdf']);
                }
                else
                {
                    $sqlIdPdf = "SELECT productid FROM product WHERE product_name = '$name'";
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sqlIdPdf);

                    if($result)
                    {   
                        $result = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
                        $result = $result['productid'];
                        $destination = "admin/productsPdf/$result/";
                        if(!file_exists(folderDirectory.$destination)){
                            mkdir(folderDirectory.$destination , 0777,true);
                        }
                        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["pdf"]["tmp_name"],folderDirectory.$destination.$filePdf);
                        $locationPdf = $destination.$filePdf;
                        // consulta de editado
                        $sqlUpPdf="UPDATE product set pdf_url = '$locationPdf' WHERE productid = $result";
                        mysqli_query($conn,$sqlUpPdf);
                        // echo json_encode(['error'=>true,'msg'=>'No se pudo ejectar la consulta, error:'.$result,'data:'=>$sqlUpPdf]);
                    }                   
                    else
                    {   $errors[] = "No se pudo ejectar la consulta, error: $result";
                        echo json_encode(['error'=>true,'msg'=>'No se pudo ejectar la consulta']);
                    }
                }
            }

            echo json_encode(['error'=>false,'msg'=>'El producto ha sido guardado con éxito.','products'=>getAllProducts($category,$conn)]);
        } 
        else {
            $errors[] = "Lo sentimos, el registro falló. Por favor, regrese y vuelva a intentarlo.";
            echo json_encode(['error'=>true,'msg'=>'Lo sentimos, el registro falló. Por favor, regrese y vuelva a intentarlo.'.mysqli_error($query)]);
        }
    }   
    else 
    {
        // echo json_encode(['error'=>true,'msg'=>'Unknow']);
    }

    function getAllProducts($idCategory,$conn){
        $tableProd="";
        $sqlRead="select * from product as p where p.categoryid = $idCategory";

        $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sqlRead);
        if($result){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                $pid = $row['productid'];
                $tableProd .="<tr>
                              <td>". $row['product_name']. "</td>
                              <td>". $row['product_price']."</td>
                              <td>". $row['product_qty'].  "</td>";
                $tableProd .="<td><button onclick='getProductEdit($pid)' class='btn btn-success btn-sm' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#editprod'><i class='fa fa-edit'></i> Edit</button>
                <button onclick='getPhoto($pid)' class='btn btn-success btn-sm' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#addphoto'><i class='fa fa-edit'></i> Add Photo</button>
                <button onclick='getProductDelete($pid,$idCategory)' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' data-toggle='modal' ><i class='fa fa-trash'></i> Delete</button></td> 
                </tr>";
            }
        }
            // echo json_encode(['error'=>false,'msg'=>'Pruduct was deleted successfully','products'=>$tableProd]);
        return $tableProd;
    }
    // Este codigo se puede optimizar aun mas
?>
```

he intentado de distintas maneras pero siempre obtengo el mismo resultado... no sé a que se debe el problema.

El cotejamiento de las tablas está en   utf8_unicode_ci.

El cotejamiento de las columnas está en utf8_spanish_ci.

Comment: Ya intentaste con el el utf8_general_ci ?

Comment: en la tabla o columna??

Comment: Puedes aplicarlo para toda la base de datos a la hora de crearla, pero si quieres se lo puedes asignar a la tabla, o a la columna

Comment: gracias voy a probar

Comment: estaba revisando y me tira este error 

"  Data too long for column 'descr' at row 1{"error":true,"msg":"Lo sentimos, el registro fall\u00f3. Por favor, regrese y vuelva a intentarlo."}  "

Comment: Revisa el tamaño del campo desc en la base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

Por ejemplo si usamos **MySQLI**

Si estamos leyendo los datos de un fichero de texto y los insertamos en nuestra tabla, puede ser que contenga caracteres especiales como:

```
¼ # Ó Ñ º ª Ø
```

Para solucionar esto, en este caso estoy obteniendo los datos que he leído del fichero de texto, y los que me interesan están a partir de la posición 29
y tienen una longitud de 40.
Los convierto en utf8, de esta forma podré insertar luego el texto tal cual, con sus caracteres especiales.

```
$Descripcion = utf8_decode(trim(substr($content, 29, 40)));
```

Pero que pasa si tenemos caracteres como `' \ ".` Entonces, seguido usaremos la siguiente línea:

```
$Descripcion = addslashes($Descripcion);
```

Así ya podemos llamar a nuestra consulta SQL:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Planos (CENTRO, PLANIF, MATERIAL, DESCRIPCION, PLANO) 
VALUES ('$Centro', '$Planif', '$Material', '$Descripcion', '$Plano') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE CENTRO='$Centro', PLANIF='$Planif', 
DESCRIPCION='$Descripcion', PLANO='$Plano'";    
$resultado = mysqli_query ($link, $sql) or die (mysql_error ());
```